# Java How do you manage layers when drawing?

Tags: java, swing, awt, graphics2d, mixing

I am using Java's AWT package to draw using Graphics2D and a BufferStrategy on a Canvas. The Canvas is placed onto a JFrame. When I place Entities from my game onto the canvas and draw them they seem to be rendered in a seemingly random order. I have a list of Entities and they are drawn using an advanced for loop. Every time I start the game, the Entities are drawn in a random order, but always the same order until I restart the program. This is the code in my loop for rendering.

```
for (Entity e : EntityManager.list) {
        e.update();
        e.draw(g, e.x, e.y);
}
```

This is my draw method:

```
public void draw(Graphics g,int x,int y) {
    g.drawImage(image,x,y,null);
}
```

I have searched quite a bit, but I haven't found a precise answer on how layers are managed by Graphics2D. Also on the Javadoc it doesn't mention how it deals with layers.

Comment: It renders over the top of the previously rendered objects

Comment: If this were so, there would not be so much randomness in the layers...

Comment: There is probably randomness in the layers because you are constantly cycling through them in your loop. They overlap in the order they are drawn in. Test it out; remove your for loop and in your render method draw an image, on the line after that draw method draw another image. The latter image will be on top of the other image

Answer (score 0):

Layers are drawn in the order that they are added to the list. In order to manage layers, you just have to create an arraylist that includes the layer and the entity and keep them ordered and you can change it around like that.

Comment: You can add a z component (draw order) to your entity.  This keeps you from having to order the List, but you do have to go over the List several times when drawing.  Or you can use a Map, with the z component being the key and the entity being the object.